# Union type of object contains boolean literal type wrapped with Promise

Tags: typescript, promise, union-types

I want to write union type of object contains boolean literal type wrapped with Promise as XHR response. But I couldn't put appropriate types.

```
type MyResponseSuccess = { data: any, error: false };
type MyResponseFailure = { message: string, error: true };
type MyResponse = MyResponseSuccess | MyResponseFailure;

function call(): Promise<MyResponse> {
  return fetch('ENDPOINT')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(payload => ({ data: payload, error: false }))
    .catch(err => ({ error: true, message: err.toString() }));
}
```

This code causes following errors. Why...? or if someone knows a workaround for this problem, please let me know.

> Type 'Promise<{ data: any; error: boolean; } | { error: boolean;
>   message: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>         Type '{ data: any; error: boolean; } | { error: boolean; message: any; }' is not assignable to type 'MyResponse'.
>           Type '{ data: any; error: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'MyResponse'.
>             Type '{ data: any; error: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'MyResponseFailure'.
>               Property 'message' is missing in type '{ data: any; error: boolean; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is we must tell the Typescript, the return type of the response. We can use `as` in this case.

```
type MyResponseSuccess = { data: any, error: false };
type MyResponseFailure = { message: string, error: true };
type MyResponse = MyResponseSuccess | MyResponseFailure;

function call(): Promise<MyResponse> {
  return fetch('ENDPOINT')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(payload => ({ data: payload, error: false } as MyResponseSuccess))
    .catch(err => ({ error: true, message: err.toString() } as MyResponseFailure));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

based on error, you can try this:

```
function call(): Promise<MyResponse> {
    return fetch('ENDPOINT')
        .then(res => {
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw new Error(res.statusText)
            }
            return res.json();
        })
        .then(payload => {
            return { data: payload, error: false }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return { message: err.toString() , error: true };
        })
}
type MyResponseSuccess = { data: any, error: boolean };
type MyResponseFailure = { message: string, error: boolean };
type MyResponse = MyResponseSuccess | MyResponseFailure;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It passes type checking but it doesn't utilize control flow analysis.

Comment: @kuy i don't get what you mean but i tried update the answer.

Comment: What did you change, other than moving the `type` declarations below the code?